# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

```
    using (EntityDataContext amdb = new EntityDataContext(StrConnectionString))
            {
                if (amdb.DatabaseExists())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        if (!isoStore.FileExists(databaseName))
                        {
                            copyDatabase = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream databaseStream = isoStore.OpenFile(databaseName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) // error here
                            {
                                using (Stream db = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(databaseName, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                                {
                                    if (databaseStream.Length < db.Length)
                                        copyDatabase = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //error with the database that has been packaged
                }
                if (copyDatabase)
                    new Worker().Copy(databaseName);
            }
```

Comment: The exception is the title to the question,

Comment: Eror occurs the first time emulator is run, after that it runs fine untill i close it

Comment: You should have included this information in the question itself, not just post your code. **Explain** what the code is trying to do and what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you precise, in isolated storage access mode parameters, the possibility to write data in there instead of just be able to read.

Did you test with a device?

Comment: error occurs when the first time emulator is run, after that i works fine until i close it

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell you're trying to read the database file, while you still have a database connection open. Since the a DataContext locks the database (and thus the file),  you're not allowed to read it at the same time.

In order to close the database connection try to close the `EntityDataContext` object (by calling `amdb.Close()` or by closing the using statement

Try something like this:

```
bool shouldCopyDatabase = false;
bool databaseExists = false;

using (EntityDataContext amdb = new EntityDataContext(StrConnectionString))
{
    databaseExists = amdb.DatabaseExists();
}

if (databaseExists == true)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!isoStore.FileExists(databaseName))
        {
            copyDatabase = true;
        }
        else
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream databaseStream = isoStore.OpenFile(databaseName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) // error here
            {
                using (Stream db = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(databaseName, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                {
                    if (databaseStream.Length < db.Length)
                        copyDatabase = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (copyDatabase)
    new Worker().Copy(databaseName);
```

By moving the isolated storage access functionality outside of the `using (EntityDataContext amdb = new EntityDataContext(StrConnectionString))` scope, you allow the database connection to be closed first.